# How to change the properties of a fontawesome icon inside a div?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I've been trying to change the icon on my website's side navigation bar to beige but I cannot seem to do it...

I am aware that I should override the icon's property in CSS to do so however, I'm not sure which property I should set

**I've tried:**

- setting .fa-twitter class position to relative
- setting .fa-twitter class color to beige
- creating a div for the icons inside the parent side navigation div
  then changing class fa-twitter's color to white

**notes:** I used a hover animation for my navigation bar so I want that to stay

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <img id="mainicon" src="mainicon.png">
    <h2>Nikukurin</h2>

    <a href="http://twitter.com/nikukurin" i class="fa fa-twitter"></a>

    <hr>
    <a id="hvr-bounce-to-right" href="#">HOME</a>
    <a id="hvr-bounce-to-right" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a id="hvr-bounce-to-right" href="#">COMMISSIONS</a>
    <a id="hvr-bounce-to-right" href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #ff9999;
  padding: 1%;
}

#mainicon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 3%;
}

.sidebar a {
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5%;
  color: beige;
  font-family: nikuhead;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5%;
}

#hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ffbc57;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

#hvr-bounce-to-right:hover,
#hvr-bounce-to-right:focus,
#hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: #ff6666;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before,
#hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before,
#hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
```

output right now:
[image]

output i want: there's supposed to be a twitter icon right under the "nikukurin" and it's supposed to be white but it's the same color as the div background

thank you for taking the time to read this and thank you for anyone answering in advanced!

Comment: This isn't valid markup: `i class="fa fa-twitter"`. What is this `i`?

Comment: Also I can't see any rule on your CSS that would target your hyperlink (ie: `.fa-twitter`)?

Comment: Should be an `i` element wrapped in the `a` (`<a href="..."><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>`. By convention, FontAwesome overloads `i` to mean "icon" instead of "italic".

Comment: hey guys! I got the answer! I posted my answer in this post in case anyone else will have this question. Thanks so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the answer!

so what i was doing wrong is particularly this line:

`<a href="http://twitter.com/nikukurin" i class="fa fa-twitter"></a>`

which was supposed to be

`<a href="http://twitter.com/nikukurin"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>`

Answer (score 0):

First thing is u are missing syntax ,

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/nikukurin"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
```

And if that doesn't change the color then:

```
.sidebar a{
    color : white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be changed to this:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/nikukurin"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> </a>
```

Comment: yep! I just figured this out a moment ago, thank you, I'll upvote this answer so people who will have the same question can see. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand the question clearly but whatever i have understood you have to first correct html syntax

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/nikukurin"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
```

it will show you the icon, then apply the css to change the icon color

```
.sidebar a{color:#F5F5DC}
```